# Eclipse cannot recognize the linked 'res' folder for an android project

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, drawable

I tried to reuse the "drawable" folder of the first android project. For the second project "drawable" file, I just created a linked folder to "res" of my first project and expected any change on the "drawable" of first project would reflected on the second one. But the system does not recognize the virtual folder, how can I fix it without copying and pasting?

Error appears on the lines like: android:background="@drawable/button_deepskyblue"

Comment: I don't think Eclipse/Android recognize virtual folders for development. You might set the 1st project as Android library project, then you can add it as a library. Not sure if that's what you want though...

Comment: why you need to create a virtual folder. Just copy the resources to your current project. Every project is separate from each other.

Comment: I guess you are on a windows machine? It should work in *nix.

Comment: I am combining two of my existing projects, one is free and the other is paid. It is painful to update on both. I tried to seperate a common library out, but I failed because the view ids and the packages were messed up. For now I just want to share the res folder since the major update is on the UI.